AC analysis error in Ltspice
I am trying to simulate my transfer function in Ltspice , my circuit is given below. When I do ac analysis, it gives me error and error is also given below.
Where do I make mistake regarding the error  ?


The pictures below are the same circuit but only Rsource is written with  {curly braces}, so now there is another warning which is given below, what is this Unknown parameter ''*'' ,   how should I solve it ?



Did you try {} around the whole expression instead of just around the individual parameters?

You can't just use parameters like that; you have to enclose them in {curly braces} to signal to LTspice that these are parameters and math operators and not the name of a model that happens to contain asterisks for some reason.
specifically in the case of B sources, this is not required, which is somewhat confusing because it doesn't work elsewhere, like in the resistor here.

You mean for example for the Rsource it should be {(N* Vin *V(d)-I(L1) *rd)/I(L1)} @Hearth

@Mhan Or something like that. I don't recall the exact syntax.

If so, the only parameter which should be changed to {curly braces} is Rsource , I put the Rsource to curly braces, it didn't work  @Hearth

@Mhan Oh, I think you have more than one issue here. I'm pretty sure you can't reference device currents or node voltages in the standard resistor formula (so that V(d) and I(L1) are not allowed there); there's a way to do what you're trying to do here, but I don't recall how exactly.

They told me to use B source to be able use V(d) or I(L1) kind values in my old questions, so I did but in case of resistor I dont know how to solve the issue, if you have any other suggestion I will be very happy  @Hearth

Ok I solved the issue, you can see the difference in the second circuit (added above in the question)  in which R source is written in a different way using the  { } hovewer this time I have another warning , can you check the new error @Hearth

@Mhan This is the same error; now it's confused because you have a * outside of curly braces.

Ok I got it, if you have any other suggestion I will be very happy @Hearth

@Mhan For a behavioral resistor you simply need to add R= to the beginning of the expression.

From the LTSpice help file (the page on .PARAM):

To invoke parameter substitution and expression evaluation, enclose the expression in curly braces. [emphasis added]

If this is correct (I haven't checked) you need to enclose the whole expression in braces ({}), not the individual parameter names.
